# Notification of comments and answers not highlighted on inbox when viewing question

Tags: discussion

There must have been a change to SO. I used to get notifications of comments and answers as a red number on my inbox.

It appears that if I am on the question screen already that these notifications do not appear.

When I am looking at the question, sure it can be annoying to see the update and also get the notification.

However, on my multi-monitor and multi tab browser, when I have the question open and I close it, or as i usually do when there is lots of stuff open, open a new instance of SO. In a way, I dont know there was an a new answer, comment etc.

Needed is either an option in my profile that controls this behaviour.

or

Still show the inbox notification red number and remove each as I click on the "an answer has been added, click here to see it.". Same for comments. If I happen to refresh the window instead; Do not remove the red number.